# A congruence for the prime counting function in Wolfram.What does it actually say?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

I saw today in [functions.wolfram.com](http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/Prime/32/01/) a congruence for the prime counting function 
which says $\binom {2prime(k)-1} {prime(k)-1} \pmod{prime(k)^3}=1$ (the third congruence at the bottom).

What does it actually say?
(prime(n) is the notation for $\pi(n)$)

I thought at the beginning that the congruence states

$\binom {2\pi(k)-1} {\pi(k)-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{(\pi(k))^3}$

which is clearly false (for $k=10$ for example $\binom {2\pi(10)-1}{\pi(10)-1}=\binom {7}{3} \equiv 1\pmod{(\pi(10))^3}$ is false.)

I would like  if someone understands what is Wolfram saying, to give me a reference or a proof of the congruence.
Thank you very much!

Comment: prime($n$) is the $n$th prime and it's not  $\pi(n)$ which refers to the number of primes less than $n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the prime counting function but the $k$-th prime.

Thus, it is asserted that 
$$ 
\binom{2p-1}{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^3}
$$
for $p$ a prime at least $5$; 
there is a condition $k>2$ there so it only holds from the third prime on.

This congruence is known as [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).